# How to show HTML in a column with aoColumns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following Data table function which is suppossed to draw a table from the  server side  :

```
function Draw() {
    oTable = j("#dataTables-example").DataTable({
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
             "sSwfPath": "/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
        stateSave: true,
        "bautoWidth": false,
        "aoColumns": [
            {"sTitle": "Role No", "mData": "id"},
            {"sTitle": "Role Name.", "mData": "name"},
            {"sTitle": "Status", "mData": "status"},
            {"sTitle": "Action","mData":""}
        ],
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 200,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "sAjaxSource": '<?php echo base_url() . "admin/roles_data"; ?>',
        "aaSorting": [[2, "desc"]]
    });
```

}

How can I add HTML in the `aoColumns` of `mData` property of the following?

```
{"sTitle": "Action","mData":""}
```

Comment: Use `bAutoWidth` instead of `bautoWidth`, or better yet, use newer notation [`autoWidth`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/autoWidth) for DataTables 1.10+.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use `sDefaultContent` (DataTables 1.9) or [`defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) (DataTables 1.10) as follows:

```
"aoColumns": [
   {"sTitle": "Role No", "mData": "id"},
   {"sTitle": "Role Name.", "mData": "name"},
   {"sTitle": "Status", "mData": "status"},
   {"sTitle": "Action", "mData": null, "sDefaultContent": '<input type="button" value="Some Action">' }
],
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zr1r4rwx/) for code and demonstration.